# How to show content of field token to client

Tags: c#, node.js, token

Response from backend: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoA2D.jpg)

I wanna take field token. Server: node.js. Client: C#. Help me!!!

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? Please read this document and revise accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Json.NET library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to do it. First find it on NuGet and reference it and then you create a class that matches the response:

```
var responseObject = JObject.Parse( response );
var token = responseObject[ "token" ].ToString();
```